# Count duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a Sale table

```
Store | Transaction | ItemID

    A | 1000 | A1
    A | 1000 | A2
    A | 1001 | A3
    A | 1001 | A3
    A | 1001 | A4
    B | 2000 | B1
    B | 2000 | B3
    B | 2001 | B2
    B | 2002 | B4
```

I would like to have query to calculate the results below:

```
Store | Total Transactions | Total Item Sales

    A | 2 | 5
    B | 3 | 4
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are very new to SQL.  The query is a simple aggregation:

```
select store, count(distinct Transaction) as NumTransactions,
       count(*) as NumItems
from t
group by store;
```

Comment: you're correctly right, I'm still learning here and thanks for the teaching... that worked